# intent.getStringExtra() returns null

Tags: android, string, kotlin, android-intent

Im trying to send data class object to another activity with intent but it returned null so i tried sending simple string but it still returns null, i couldn't find what is the problem. Here is my code

code in LoginScreen.kt

```
val intentUser = Intent(this@LoginScreen,HomeActivity::class.java)
val string = "intent"
intentUser.putExtra("intent",string)
startActivity(intentUser)
finish()
```

and code in my HomeActivity

```
val intentUser = Intent()
var string = intentUser.getStringExtra("intent")
Log.e("Intent: ",string.toString())
```

result

```
2022-02-23 14:25:09.139 11365-11365/com.scibilisim.d_forceandroid E/Intent:: null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `HomeActivity` you are initializing intent as

```
intent = Intent()
```

This actually initializes the intent with a new intent object. That is not desired behavior, to achieve desired behavior use `getIntent()` instead of `Intent()`.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this in your `LoginScreen.kt`:

```
val intentUser = Intent(this@LoginScreen,HomeActivity::class.java)
val string = "intent"
intentUser.putString("intent",string)
startActivity(intentUser)
this.finish()
```

and in your `HomeActivity`:

```
val string = intent!!.getStringExtra("intent")
```

The error is that you are instantiating a new Intent object.